# Cause of ExecuteError: ERROR 999999: Error executing function from Spatial Join?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.1, error-999999

I'm trying to use the spatial join to append rows to my target feature from my join feature. Here's my code:

```
#import the module
import arcpy
from arcpy.sa import *
from arcpy import env
env.overwriteOutput = True

#set the workspace
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Users\Windows\Documents\JO_GIS_Analyst"

#Adding the municipality to the attribute table
for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("reclassnofptphil_onlyreprojected_2014121_geog*"):
    print fc #checking of feature classes
    outputFeature = "withjoin" + fc # specify output feature
    arcpy.SpatialJoin_analysis(fc, "PHL_adm2_UTM.shp", outputFeature)


print "Finish"
```

I'm getting an error of:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Windows\Dropbox\Python Scripts\batch_convert_raster_to_polygon.py", line 71, in <module>
arcpy.SpatialJoin_analysis(fc, "PHL_adm2_UTM.shp", outputFeature)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\analysis.py", line 481, in SpatialJoin
raise e
ExecuteError: ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
Item not found in this collection.
Failed to execute (SpatialJoin).
```

Here is the ouput of the print statement:

```
 reclassnofptphil_onlyreprojected_2014121_geog.shp
```

Actually I'm doing a loop for six files only, since I'm just using my sample files to test my code.

Comment: That's a VERY long name for a feature class, try it with a shorter name... Is PHL_adm2_UTM.shp in your current workspace ("C:\Users\Windows\Documents\JO_GIS_Analyst")? if not it will not find it, use the full path.

Comment: Yes, PHL_adm2_UTM.shp is in the current workspace.

Comment: I think you should try running the Spatial Join tool manually from its tool dialog with exactly the same parameter values that your script is supplying.

Comment: Hello, I checked the output file shapefile and it seemed that my code worked but the error 999999 returned.

Comment: Maybe, there is a problem with the implementation of my for loop, since only a single fc is processed, and the script returns an error.

Comment: Are there any *naughty* characters in the rest of the feature class path? ArcGis cannot create shapefiles with characters other than 0-9 and a to z with the only non-alphanumeric character being underscore. Other software can create shapefiles with a dash (-) or hash (#) in the file name, ArcGis will read them fine but will NOT create them, try doing outputFeature.replace("-","_") to turn dashes into underscores if that is the case.

Comment: I think you should include the output of the `print` statement in your question.  There's no need to do this for all iterations just the last couple of successful ones and then the one that throws the error.